# PHP If/Else Statement not working with embedded HTML Code

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to write a function which takes images from a database and presents them on the webpage within different sized borders depending on the image size. When I try to parse this code within the browser, I get an unexpected T_else error. Can anybody explain where I've gone wrong? Thanks

```
<?
$cakepicsql = mysql_query("SELECT * from cakes WHERE category = '".$cake['category']."'      ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($cakepic = mysql_fetch_array( $cakepicsql ))  {

    $image_path = "http://WEBSITE/products/"; 
    $filename = $image_path + $_GET['id'] + "-1.jpg";
    $size = getimagesize($filename);
    if ($size[0] > $size[1])
        echo "<a href="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/<?=$cake['category_p']?>"><img src="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/products/<?=$cakepic['id']?>-1.jpg" alt="<?=$cake['name']?>" width="280" height="274" border="0" class="rounded-image" /></a> ";
    else
        echo "<a href="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/<?=$cake['category_p']?>"><img src="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/products/<?=$cakepic['id']?>-1.jpg" alt="<?=$cake['name']?>" width="202" height="274" border="0" class="rounded-image" /></a>";
    endif;
} ?>      
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Tip: you don't need closing `?>` and opening `<?php` PHP tags between two lines of PHP. Only to separate PHP from raw output. It just makes your code more difficult to read.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: AFAICT the only difference is the value of width and height, so really you just just change those in your link instead of echoing the whole thing. Your quoting is probably wrong - use double quotes to enclose the string and single quotes inside it to make life simple

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using alternate control structures, you need `:` after each command, so:

```
<? if ($size[0] > $size[1]) ?>
```

should be

```
<? if ($size[0] > $size[1]): ?>
```

and

```
<? else ?>
```

should be

```
 <? else: ?>
```

Moreover, this is pretty messy, all those opening and closing output tags. Just do the whole thing inside a normal PHP bracket (`<?php` / `?>`) and use `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <?php
    $cakepicsql = mysql_query("SELECT * from cakes WHERE category = '".$cake['category']."'      ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); 
     while($cakepic = mysql_fetch_array( $cakepicsql ))  {
      $image_path = "http://WEBSITE/products/"; 
      $filename = $image_path + $_GET['id'] + "-1.jpg"; 
      $size = getimagesize($filename); 
   if ($size[0] > $size[1]) {
   <a href='http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/<?php echo $cake["category_p2"];?>'><img src="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/products/<?php echo $cakepic['id']; ?>-1.jpg" alt="<?php echo $cake['name'];?>" width="280" height="274" border="0" class="rounded-image" /></a>
 } else{ 
 <a href="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/<?php echo $cake['category_p'];?>"><img src="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/products/<?php echo $cakepic['id'];?>-1.jpg" alt="<?php echo $cake['name'];?>" width="202" height="274" border="0" class="rounded-image" /></a>
   }
   } 
 ?>      
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better:

```
<?php
$cakepicsql = mysql_query("SELECT * from cakes WHERE category = '".$cake['category']."'      ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($cakepic = mysql_fetch_array( $cakepicsql ))  {

 $image_path = "http://WEBSITE/products/"; 
 $filename = $image_path + $_GET['id'] + "-1.jpg"; 
 $size = getimagesize($filename); 
 if ($size[0] > $size[1]):
?>
     <a href="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/<?=$cake['category_p']?>"><img src="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/products/<?=$cakepic['id']?>-1.jpg" alt="<?=$cake['name']?>" width="280" height="274" border="0" class="rounded-image" /></a>
 <?php
  else:
?>
  <a href="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/<?=$cake['category_p']?>"><img src="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/products/<?=$cakepic['id']?>-1.jpg" alt="<?=$cake['name']?>" width="202" height="274" border="0" class="rounded-image" /></a>
 <?php endif;
  }  
?> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

You just need ":" in your if/else statement and you don't need to open and close PHP tag on every line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cakepicsql = mysql_query("SELECT * from cakes WHERE category = '".$cake['category']."'      ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($cakepic = mysql_fetch_array( $cakepicsql ))  {
    $image_path = "http://WEBSITE/products/";
    $filename = $image_path + $_GET['id'] + "-1.jpg"; 
    $size = getimagesize($filename);
    if ($size[0] > $size[1]) 
        echo "<a href='http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/".$cake['category_p']."'><img src='http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/products/'".$cakepic['id']."-1.jpg' alt='".$cake['name']."' width='280' height='274' border='0' class='rounded-image' /></a>";
    else
        echo "<a href='http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/".$cake['category_p']."'><img src='http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/products/".$cakepic['id']."-1.jpg' alt='".$cake['name']."' width='202' height='274' border='0' class='rounded-image' /></a>";
 } 
?>      
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think HEREDOCs make your code look neater and easier to fix, and avoids the quoting problems in your original....

```
<?php
$sql = <<<EOF
SELECT * from cakes
WHERE category = '{$cake['category']}'
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
EOF;

$cakepicquery = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($cakepic = mysql_fetch_array( $cakepicquery ))  {

    $image_path = "http://WEBSITE/products/"; 
    $filename = $image_path + $_GET['id'] + "-1.jpg";
    $size = getimagesize($filename);
    $height = 274;
    $width = ($size[0] > $size[1]) ? 280 : 202;
    echo <<<EOF
<a href="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/{$cake['category_p']}">
    <img src="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/products/{$cakepic['id']}-1.jpg" alt="{$cake['name']}" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" border="0" class="rounded-image" />
</a>
EOF;
} ?>    
</td>
</tr>
```

Incidentally, your loop seems a little confused in terms of variable use. If you're working out the URL once, you don't need to do it a second time. Why are using _GET['id'] in one location and an ID from the database in another?

```
  echo <<<
<a href="http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/{$cake['category_p']}">
    <img src="{$filename}" alt="{$cake['name']}" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" border="0" class="rounded-image" />
</a>
EOF;
```

Comment: When running this code, I get the following error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL, expecting ',' or ';' in /homepages ...

Comment: Fixed a missing EOF :-).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes in your echos. To include quotes inside a string you either need to use a different quote, eg: `echo "width='280'";` or escape the quotes, eg: `echo "width=\"280\""`  Otherwise you are ending the string making the PHP expect code to follow.

Plus you seem to be trying to embed PHP code in PHP code.

To include a PHP array value in a string you need to write it like this:

```
echo "<a href='http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/".$cake['category_p']."'>
```

So for example, this line should look like:

```
echo "<a href='http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/".$cake['category_p']."'><img src='http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/products/".$cakepic['id']."-1.jpg' alt='".<?=$cake['name']."' width='280' height='274' border='0' class='rounded-image' /></a>";
```

EDIT: just to add that I agree with others, building sections of your string (Eg. `$filename = "http://www.WEBSITE.co.uk/shop/cakes/<?=$cake['category_p']?>"`) does look neater, plus makes maintaining the code easier, should you have to change something later.